# Can Frankenstein's Golem wear women's clothing on Purim?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

We know that Rebbe Victor Frankenstein created a golem (the English called it a monster) during the 18th century. Since Frankenstein was Jewish, I've been wondering about the halakhot that apply to his creation.

Specifically, does the golem get to dress up in Purim, even if in women's clothing?

The Rema famously states (O'C 696:8):

> ומה שנהגו ללבוש פרצופים בפורים, וגבר לובש שמלת אשה ואשה כלי גבר, אין איסור בדבר מאחר שאין מכוונין אלא לשמחה בעלמא

However, other authorities strongly object to this, especially the Genevan poskim from which R. Frankenstein would have relied on. Is the golem considered a male for this to even be considered an issue?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: If you can use a golem for a minyan, and you can't use women for a minyan....

Comment: @Shokhet a golem cannot be used for a minyan as per chacham tzvi. The Mishna Berurah just didn't quote the actual psak, he merely referenced it. Also acc to sanhedrin 65b he wouldn't be able to say Amen cause he can't talk:)

Comment: @aryeh Technically, a golem does not have a soul, so it is not human. It can wear anything. I would advise that if the golem wants to wear something let it do what it wants or there may be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure to create a golem is described by Rashi in Sanhedrin 65b as being done with the Seffer Yetzira by using letter combinations, צרוף אותיות.

What's quite obvious is that the word צרוף is used to preclude פרצוף by lack of the letter פ׳.

This is understood on a deeper level when we concider that the letter פ׳ corresponds to the passuk וירא אלקים כי טוב. This proves that the golem must be visible, and not covered.

So in fact a golem may not wear any costume whatsoever.

If this concerns a practical ruling C.Y.L.O.M(ekubal).